# Using this.prototype.show in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, ecmascript-5

Previously Modal was a function and define like this

```
function Modal (heading){
               this.modal="Hello"; //works fine
               Modal.prototype.show = function(){ // Not working
                     $('#exceptionModal').modal('show');
               }    
 }
```

I tried to convert it for requirejs Module

```
define("wbModal", function(){
    return{
            Modal: function(heading){
                   this.modal="Hello"; //works fine
                   this.prototype.show = function(){ // Not working
                         $('#exceptionModal').modal('show');
                   }
            }
    }
}
```

I can't find whats wrong with that, if `this.modal`can work so why `this.prototype.show` not working?

Following are can b found in console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'show' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly as the error message tells you, `this.prototype` is `undefined`, so of course you can't set properties on it. You're confusing anonymous functions with constructor functions.

Try this:

```
define("wbModal", function() {
    function ModalConstructor(heading) {
        this.modal = "Hello";
    }

    ModalConstructor.prototype.show = function() {
        // you'll probably want to use `this` in some way here
        $('#exceptionModal').modal('show');
    };

    return {
        Modal: ModalConstructor
    }
}
```

Or this:

```
define("wbModal", function() {

    return {
        Modal: function(heading) {
            this.modal = "Hello";
            this.show = function() {
                $('#exceptionModal').modal('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was the object previously and I am trying to convert it into modal. So it was having constructors. How could I make it work for me ?

Comment: Please edit the question to show what was working before, how you were calling it before, and how you're trying to call it now.

Comment: I have added more detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.prototype.show = function({ // Not working
                 $('#exceptionModal').modal('show');
           });
```

This is what you should be typing. Check the braces.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is the object that inherits from the prototype of `Modal`. It doesn't have an internal `[[Prototype]]` property. You simply define the method on the object:

```
this.show = function() {

};
```

Comment: No I want to use it as constructor.

Comment: So you want things to inherit from objects that inherit from `Modal`?

Comment: i just want to define a constructor for a function and class definition style cannot be changed.